# why does kops keeps almost half the CIDR unused while creating k8s cluster?

Tags: cidr, kops, kubernetes

Kops assigns 1/8 th of the CIDR to its private subnets each, and 1/64 th of the CIDR to its utility subnets.

If we create a multi AZ cluster with 1024 IPs having three zones, 
private Subnets would cover **1/8*1024*3 = 384 IPs**
utility subnets would cover **1/64*1024*3 = 48 IPs**.
which is 432 combined.

- which is more or less half of 1024. Why are so many IPs left unused?
- Why does kops distributes IPs this way? (1/8 the of the CIDR to private subnets in each AZ).

Answer (score 0):

Because kops is used with many different types of workloads, it comes with defaults, but allows you to configure the subnets as you desire. Using `kops edit cluster` you can edit the `cidr` attribute on each of the subnes in `spec.subnets` to whatever you'd like them to be.